# Capturing screen while Incoming Call on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to capture screen (take screenshot) on iPhone (Using for example: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext) while incoming call is in process or while the iPhone rings?

tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't have access to the screen when the call is ringing.

- Press power and home buttons together to do a system screenshot?
- Use the screenshots section in the Xcode Organizer to capture the screen while tethered?

When a call is in progress you can press Home and re-open your app.

At that point you could use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` but it *probably* won't include the statusbar or green 'in progress' bar.

Comment: well.. i need to capture while my app is in the background, and automatically on incoming call.. i guess it's impossible.

Comment: There is too much potential for abuse/spying to allow that I guess.